# Viewstate storing data?

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net, viewstae is it client variable or server variable? how much data can view state is store. I mean if i declare a view state, when more than one user accessing same page is the view state data can conflict or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe ASP.NET ViewState is a client side hidden control which stores some state data for ASP.NET server controls. The content is Base64 encoded and can be seen with a decoder. It is only available on a postback to the same page. Different users have their own ViewState as it is a client side technology. You can store as much data as you want, but it affects the bandwith. In general you should watch out for large ViewState because it is also not very SEO friendly.

You can use it for your own data like this:

```
ViewState["myData1"] = someSerializableContent;
ViewState["myData2"] = someSerializableContent;
```

The ViewState is protected by a hash code to prevent manipulation.

EDIT: Basically you can add as many entries into the ViewState collection as you want. Sometimes it is wise to disable ViewState at all (EnableViewState property). In ASP.NET 4.0 you have more options to disable/enable ViewState by using the ViewStateMode property.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Slfan, how many viewstate can i create per a page

Answer (score 2):

You're really going to want to read this, It covers pretty much all of your questions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx